# replicating an excel solver function in python to get required output

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, solver

assuming I got cashflows from year 1 through year 4
cf = [30,45,52,67]

and discount rates (zero coupon)
rt = [.02,.03,.04,.05]

calculating PV is straight fwd in python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cf = [30,45,52,67]
rt = [.02,.03,.04,.05]

sum([x[0]/(1+x[1])**(i+1) for i,x in enumerate(zip(cf,rt))])
```

gives me the output
`173.1775`

Now, if I want my NPV to be 180 (hypothetically), I will simply run a solve in excel and that will adjust my "rt" (by adding a spread across the board)

[image]
How do I replicate the same in python? I have seen/ used SciPy optimize for other purpose, but unsure how do I use it here (or if there is any other solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using `newton` (an implementation of the Newton-Raphson method) from `scipy.optimize`.

`newton` needs a starting point and a function of a single parameter that evaluates to zero when you reach your target (this is not truly true, `newton` can accept also functions of more than one variable, but…) so we write a function that accepts your arguments and returns the function needed by `newton`, and at last we call `newton`with the initial value of zero

```
In [25]: from scipy.optimize import newton
    ...: cf = [30,45,52,67]
    ...: rt = [.02,.03,.04,.05]
    ...: 
    ...: def make_fun(cf, ret, val):
    ...:     def fun(d):
    ...:         return val-sum([x[0]/(1+x[1]+d)**(i+1)for i,x in enumerate(zip(cf,rt))])
    ...:     return fun
    ...: 
    ...: newton(make_fun(cf, rt, 180), 0)
Out[25]: -0.014576385759418057
```

---

Edit: of course you can choose a more descriptive name for `make_fun` …

Comment: perfect!! thanks for the code and the explanation - most helpful!!